# Combining two dataTables based on commonalities JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following database structure: a Project that has multiple sub-projects  and multiple users that have booked some time on a specific sub-project. I need to display for each project the list of sub-projects and for each sub-project the users working on it and the total time booked.
Like this:

```
Project1
   Subproject1       User1   TimeBooked
                     User2   TimeBooked 

   Subproject2       User3   TimeBooked 
                     User2   TimeBooked
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<p:dataTable var="subproj"
             value="#{project_stats_user_chart.selectedProject.subprojects}"
             id="projectSubprojects">

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{subproj.type}" style="font-size: 1em;"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable var="user"
                     value="#{project_stats_user_chart.users}" 
                     id="SubprojectsUsers">

            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}"
                              style="font-size: 1em;"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}" style="font-size: 1em;">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My problem now is displaying the booked time as needed.
I have a query calculating the sum on each sub-project per user but I need somehow to iterate over these two tables based on their commonalities or merge the two tables so I can get the combination I want. I am new to PrimeFaces so perhaps somebody could help me with this

Comment: I do not guess/understand relationships between tables in the database. The term *commonalities* you used makes makes me think that the relationships between tables in the database is wonky. If the same user is allowed to participate in multiple sub-projects (which in turn looks quite intuitive, by the way even though not explicitly mentioned) then, the relationships should go like this : There should be four tables in your database to maintain what you said. I choose arbitrary names. `project`, `user_table`, `sub_project` and `sub_project_user`. To be continued.

Comment: The `project` table maintains information about projects. The `sub_project` table maintains information about sub-projects. The `user_table` table maintains information about users and most importantly  `sub_project_user` is a *join table* representing/expressing a many-to-many relationship between users and sub-projects. You might unnecessarily be fiddling with a completely different problem on the front-end side, if the relationships between tables in the database were not maintained properly. To be continued.

Comment: A single mistake on the database side should never be taken lightly. Otherwise, the problem will go/remain unsolvable forever at least in a way that it should be solved/handled. (Off side : It is like reporting in which you are also supposed to combine other JSF/PrimeFaces components in conjunction with a `<p:dataTable>` such as `<p:dataGrid>`, `<p:dataList>` sub-tables etc. They are demonstrated on the showcase itself).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! My problem is not with the database but rather in the xhtml when I have to display the Combination project-subproject-user-time booked. By commonalities I mean the ids. I read something about dynamic dataTables but I am not sure it applies here.

Comment: You seem to have been maintaining only two tables namely `project` (the parent table) and `sub_project` (a child table of the `project` table). In the provided snippet (the first one in the question), `User2` is being repeated across `Subproject1` and `Subproject2`. As said in the previous comments, if this is the scenario then, you will have to consider an addition join table joining `project` and `user_table` expressing a many-to-many relationship between the said tables. The front-end problem is fully transparently dependent upon the wrong table relationships. Do not ignore it.

Comment: this is what I need because a user can work on multiple subprojects. My problem is displaying the inner join because I don't have a type for it.

Comment: Through out the question and comments, I have been getting only one impression. A user is associated with multiple sub-projects and a sub-project is in turn also associated with multiple users resulting in a mapping cardinality - many-to-many which should be expressed using a join table. By this, I guess, if you have it, you will have a precise way to query the database to get the desired result you want at any time which you can in turn easily display on the front-end too. Am I going wrong? If this is something wrong then, all of my assumptions in all of these comments are wrong.

Comment: I am a disclaimer of the last two or three sentences in the question that I do not understand precisely and this, "*I don't have a type for it*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in Java (model) side, not in XHTML (view) side. You should in Java side prepare exactly the model the view expects. The view should be kept as dumb as possible and just present the model it was given to.